# is there a VisualStudio keyboard shortcut to hide Find Results windw?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

After I do a find, I have to use the mouse to hide the Find Results window.

Is there a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Escape button? Or try Ctrl+F4

Comment: Just record a macro and bind it to a key.

Comment: Hans:  What?!  But that's work!  :-)   Thanks I will try.
Somesh:  Neither works.

Comment: Hans: that worked.  I created macro for ctrl-F ctrl-F to close.

Comment: Bad news!  The solution caused ctrl-F the shortcut to find, to stop working.

Comment: PROBLEM:  Assigned ctrl-F ctrl-F to close macro deleted find key.
SOLUTION: Used ctrl-Alt-F for close and re-assigned ctrl-F to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to make  hide the find or replace window.  here's how:

1. Dock the find or replace results window
2. Right-click its title bar, and select "auto hide".

Now, whenever you find or replace, it pops up in its docked position, and shows you the result,
and when you press , it disappears.

Answer (score 5):

Shift+Escape works for me for closing the Find results window.